# How to read specific value from thousands cells in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have data structure like below on the screen:
https://gyazo.com/fdbc15aa55a21649d238241184277aa4
ID column has thousands records. 
Every id has different prices in each country(max 4 values because there are 4 countries). 
I would like to get a price for specified ID in every country using formula. 
I was using if condition, count conditions etc. but it doesn't work when I have range of cells, not a single column.
I wanted to create it by IF(AND(ID-from-all-cells=selected-id;country=selected-country);cell-with-price;"-") - when condition is false and  price doesnt exist

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would like to get price for every ID in every country. Id is able to have 4 different prices.

Comment: Power Query can transform the table for each country vaules.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$11, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($F2, $A$2:$A$11), ROW($A$2:$C$11)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$C$11))+1), COLUMN(A$1)), ROW(A$1)),"")
```

[image: Formula]

Drag it to fill the other cells

[image: Result]

Comment: Sorry for the wrong wording of the question. In this place where is Price_Country I mean for example price_in_USA, price_in_China for every id, is it possible to change it or rather no? Anyway thanks for help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @BarbaraWojtyna China appears twice for the ID ggg. What will be the price? 30 or 6 (or even 36)?